# Typo: [transimpedence] is wrong, [transimpedance] is right, but far less popular

Tags: support, tag-cleanup, tag-blacklist-request

We'll need to retag 89 questions with [transimpedence](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transimpedence). Is there a script that can automate that?

Also, can we please blacklist [transimpedence](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transimpedence)?

Comment: A moderator can create a tag synonym and "merge".

Comment: It would probably be best to do a tag synonym merge, there isn't a good way to rename or blacklist tags. To blacklist all tags need to be removed/relabeled.

Comment: @VoltageSpike all onboard with that. How to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tags have been merged, enjoy.

Comment: Thank you very much, I do enjoy!

Comment: As much as I misspell, that misspelling is annoying.